# Error Symfony 4 with DataTables Omines bundle

Tags: symfony, datatables

I will want to know how to make the DataTables bundle works because I have not been able to make it work.

I executed this command "composer require omines/datatables-bundle".
After this, I executed "php bin/console assets:install".
I also added the dependencies.

But when i go on my page i have this error you have requested a non-exist service "Omines \ DataTablesBundle \ DataTableFactory".

Can you help me please ?

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\AdminUserFormType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Column\TextColumn;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Adapter\ArrayAdapter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Controller\DataTablesTrait;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

    use DataTablesTrait;

    /**
     * @Route("/admin/user/test", name="users_test")
     */
    public function usersTest(Request $request){
        $table = $this->createDataTable()
            ->add('firstName', TextColumn::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextColumn::class)
            ->createAdapter(ArrayAdapter::class, [
                ['firstName' => 'Donald', 'lastName' => 'Trump'],
                ['firstName' => 'Barack', 'lastName' => 'Obama'],
            ])
            ->handleRequest($request);

        if ($table->isCallback()) {
            return $table->getResponse();
        }

        return $this->render('users/test.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
    }
}
```

Comment: check if the bundle services is working. `php bin/console debug:container`

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\AdminUserFormType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Column\TextColumn;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Adapter\ArrayAdapter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTableFactory;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    protected datatableFactory;
    public function __construct(DataTableFactory $datatableFactory) {
       $this->datatableFactory = $datatableFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin/user/test", name="users_test")
     */
    public function usersTest(Request $request){
        $table = $this->datatableFactory->create([])
            ->add('firstName', TextColumn::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextColumn::class)
            ->createAdapter(ArrayAdapter::class, [
                ['firstName' => 'Donald', 'lastName' => 'Trump'],
                ['firstName' => 'Barack', 'lastName' => 'Obama'],
            ])
            ->handleRequest($request);

        if ($table->isCallback()) {
            return $table->getResponse();
        }

        return $this->render('users/test.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I change my code. My class extends AbstractController. I copy and paste your but but i have an error syntaxe for "protected datatableFactory;
    public function __construct(DataTableFactory $datatableFactory) {
       $this->datatableFactory = $datatableFactory;
    }"

Comment: Add use Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTableFactory; ?

Comment: Yes I add "use Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTableFactory"

Comment: Remove use DataTablesTrait; and change $this->createDataTable() with $this->datatableFactory->create([])

Answer (score 0):

```
class UsersController extends AbstractController
{
    use DataTablesTrait;
    protected datatableFactory;
    public function __construct(DataTableFactory $datatableFactory) {
       $this->datatableFactory = $datatableFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin/user/test", name="users_test")
     */
    public function usersTest(Request $request){
        $table = $this->createDataTable()
            ->add('firstName', TextColumn::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextColumn::class)
            ->createAdapter(ArrayAdapter::class, [
                ['firstName' => 'Donald', 'lastName' => 'Trump'],
                ['firstName' => 'Barack', 'lastName' => 'Obama'],
            ])
            ->handleRequest($request);

        if ($table->isCallback()) {
            return $table->getResponse();
        }

        return $this->render('users/test.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't extend `AbstractController`:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyClass extends Controller{}
```